# Forcing termination of app when accepting incoming call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to force quit my app when I pressed the Answer button in the incoming call and when I tap on to Reject the app should continue its working.

I had tried by pacing exit(0) in applicationDidEnterBackground.

The app is force quitting . but the problem is its relaunching automatically by itself.

Any suggestion and Ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never ever call "`exit`" within your app code.  Apple **WILL** reject apps that quit out on their own, where the user isn't doing it explicitly.  Apple says as much [in their "iOS Human Interface Guidelines" (look in the "Don't Quit Programatically" section)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1)

The only official & approved way to quit an app is for the user to manually do it by tapping on the home bar button and then hitting the "-" badge on the shaking apps in the "mini" dock.

I'd say the only thing you should do in this case is handle things properly in the [`applicationWillResignActive:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) app delegate method.

Comment: How can I candle .. my requirement is that when I accept incoming call it shut terminate.

Comment: When it comes to what your client or employer wants versus what Apple will allow on the app store, Apple *always* wins.  You'll have to offer your client a better alternative (exit the game but don't quit the app, suspend whatever is going on but don't allow re-entry easily, etc.).

Comment: I handle the application not to run in background. But in the situation when an incoming call comes when I accepted and later I ended the call the application is automatically launching does it is its behaviour anything wrong I done?

Comment: So when the incoming call finishes, the user goes right back into the app or does the user have to click on the app icon to go back into it (which picks up where they left off)?  If it's the latter, you can catch that with UIApplicationDelegate's `applicationWillEnterForeground` method.

Comment: When the incoming call finishes the user has to click on the app icon again to launch it.And it should not show where the screen user left. It should start freshly from the beginning.

Comment: So when you detect "`applicationWillEnterForeground`" being called, start freshly from the beginning. It's that easy.

Comment: I got very useful info from ur side +1.. ;)